# side loading apk android nougat

Tags: android, debugging, android-7.0-nougat

Attempting to get an unsigned debug Android APK that could be sideloaded by my beta testers.  Working with a AVD Nougat device which has it's settings / unknown sources enabled.  I email the apk as an attachment to a gmail account and click the attachment in an attempt to install it.

The device is reporting  "Error staging apk from content URI" when attempting to sideload the application.  logcat shows a filenotfoundexception for content://downloads/my_downloads/12.  The exception is generated in PackagerInstallerActivity.java (android code).

My manifest is:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.labs.timo.besafe">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/avoid_it"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name="com.labs.timo.besafe.MainActivity"
        android:label=""
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.labs.timo.besafe.DetailActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_detail_activity"
        android:parentActivityName="com.labs.timo.besafe.MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.labs.timo.besafe.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.labs.timo.besafe.SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
        android:parentActivityName="com.labs.timo.besafe.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SettingsTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.labs.timo.besafe.MainActivity" />
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.labs.timo.besafe.AboutActivity"
        android:label="About"
        android:parentActivityName="com.labs.timo.besafe.MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.labs.timo.besafe.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

Were there changes made in Nougat that I need to make to get the beta app to load?  APK installs on all versions from 4.3 on with the exception of 7.0.

Comment: More information:  sent the apk to a gmail account, click on the attachment on a Nougat AVD and get "There was a problem parsing the package".  But, I click on the APK in the Downloads application and it installs just fine.  The logcat entry indicates that Nougat is looking in the wrong directory when attempting the initial install.